# How to build a git branch with Maven scm:bootstrap

Tags: git, maven-scm

Is it possible to use the Maven scm:bootstrap goal of the scm plugin to build a specific git branch WITHOUT specifying this in the POM?

I know I could do this by specifying the branch with the <scmVersion> and <scmVersionType> parameters in the POM but it seems wrong to me somehow to change the POM for every branch I might want built.

I find that even if I checkout the branch, the bootstrap goal will build the master.  How may I specify this on the command line?

Answer (score 0):

Duh.  Just do

```
mvn -DscmVersion=whatever, -DscmVersionType=branch scm:bootstrap
```